# WPF equivalent of LVS_EX_ONECLICKACTIVATE?

Tags: wpf, listbox

I've got a WPF application with a `ListBox` in it. For this list box, I'd like to mimic the behaviour of the users control panel (since Windows Vista) -- that is: you single-click on a list item, and it's the same as double-clicking.

In Win32, I'd do this by turning on the LVS_EX_ONECLICKACTIVATE style.

In WPF, I've attempted to do this by handling the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event. Unfortunately, and this is odd, it sometimes picks up the wrong item.

For example, if you double-click the title bar (caption) to maximise the window, the second mouse-up occurs over the list box, and the event is raised. Similarly, if an item is partially in view, clicking on it scrolls it into view, but the mouse-up is raised against the item that's *now* in view, not the one clicked.

Now, again, if this was Win32 (before LVS_EX_ONECLICKACTIVATE), I'd get mouse capture on the mouse down, remember the item, and check that I had capture on mouse up.

But it's not Win32, it's WPF. How do I do single-click activation in a WPF list box?

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I never stumbled across the LVS_EX_ONECLICKACTIVATE by now, but as I understood it handling "SelectionChanged" should do the trick.

Or is there a difference between double clicking on selection or activation on selection?

Comment: That'd probably work, but I was also wondering if there was a way to get the keyboard accessibility that one-click-activate gets you in Win32.

Comment: Ah ok, the "SelectionChanged" event would probably also fire when the arrow keys are used for navigation, which is of course not acceptable.